# Is Swift generic type can be inferred while initial?

Tags: swift, generics

```
//generic queue data object
class QNode<T> {
    var key: T? = nil
    var next: QNode? = nil
}

public class Queue<T> {
//Q1    
private var top: QNode<T>! = QNode<T>()
    //enqueue the specified object
    func enQueue(var key: T) {
        //check for the instance
        if (top == nil) {
          //Q2
            top = QNode()
        }
        //establish the top node
        if (top.key == nil) {
            top.key = key
            return
        }
        var childToUse: QNode<T> = QNode<T>()
        var current: QNode = top
//cycle through the list of items to get to the end.
        while (current.next != nil) {
            current = current.next! }
//append a new item
        childToUse.key = key
        current.next = childToUse
    }
}
```

If change Q1 to private var top: QNode! = QNode() will prompt error "Argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred", but in original code Q2 is work fine without error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some interesting behaviour here, because while it is true thanks to type inference that:

```
var top: QNode<String> = QNode()
```

is the same as writing

```
var top: QNode<String> = QNode<String>()
```

or indeed

```
var top: QNode = QNode<String>()
```

The implicit unwrapping using ! creates some unusual behaviour where the compiler, though it tells us that it interprets

```
private var top: QNode! = QNode<T>()
```

as being of type `QNode<T>!` if we alt click on the variable name, in fact it behaves differently to:

```
private var top: QNode<T>! = QNode<T>()
```

or

```
 private var top: QNode<T>! = QNode()
```

This confusion in the compiler looks to me like a bug, because it should either treat `QNode!` as `QNode<T>!` or reject it altogether. Luckily, being aware of the bug you can work around it by simply using `QNode<T>!`.

I'd also file this bug with Apple, although I can't reproduce this in isolation and will take a closer look when I get a chance.

Comment: You use type <String> to demonstrate this issue? <String> could to be any type ?

Comment: The first three lines of extracted code are an example. The final three are specific to your case. You can substitute String with T or indeed with another type.

Comment: The type inference have a hard time to adapting, there are no principle that  will let you know when will it effective.

Comment: Two things are happening in the examples, one is type inference, e.g. `var a = Int()` or `var a = "string"`, where the compiler opts for the type of its choosing, and the other is where the programmer assigns the type, e.g. `var:Float = 5.2`. Doing this meanwhile `var a:String = "string"`, does nothing to change the type because it would be inferred correctly anyway. So essentially as long as the code makes obvious in some way the type the compiler will be happy. (i.e. You can add String but you don't need to in final snippet.)